Split a panda dataframe in sub-dataframes based on varying column values
I have a panda dataframe whose data are similar to those shown in the table below.



index
A
B
C




1
0.5
10
100


2
1
10
100


3
1.5
10
100


4
2
10
100


5
2.5
10
100


6
1.5
8
100


7
1.5
9
100


8
1.5
10
100


9
1.5
11
100


10
1.5
12
100


11
1.5
10
60


12
1.5
10
80


13
1.5
10
100


14
1.5
10
120


15
1.5
10
140



Basically, I have three columns and the values of the column is equal to a baseline value (1.5 for A, 10 for B and 100 for C).
In the first 5 rows, I vary A value from 0.5 up to 2.5 and B and C are constant.
In the subsequent 5 rows, I vary B value from 8 up to 12 and A and C are constant.
In the last 5 rows, I vary C value from 60 up to 140 and A and B are constant.
Based on a dataframe looking like this, I want to create 3 sub-dataframes, each of them containing only the rows in which A/B or C vary.
So for example, dataframeA containing row 1-5, dataframe B containing row 6-10 and dataframe C containing row 11-15
Now, I would like an automated procedure which does not know apriori:

how many subdataframe you need (we could have even more than 3 columns)
how many elements the sub-dataframe should have (for example I don't know if A varies in 5 rows or more)
the number of the rows corresponding to the variation (for example, I don't know that A varies between row 1 and 5)

I have thought about using groupby, but I don't think it fits this case, as I want to group based on a varying parameter and not a fixed value.
I also thought about kmeans cluster but I also don't think it is applicable here
Any smart ideas?
I am using dataframes (pandas) but maybe also other methods/package could be used in this case?
Thanks a lot

You can use .groupby and pass a list of tuples gor whether the values are different from the base values.  This assumes that you know the base values.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        A=[1.2,0.5,3.4,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        B=[10, 10,10,10,10,10,11,12,7],
        C=[100,100,100,98,102,106,100,100,100],
    )
)

# get name of column which has a value that has not changed.
condition = pd.from_dummies(
    df.ne(dict(A=1, B=10, C=100))
).iloc[:, 0]

groups = df.groupby(condition)

Note, that there must only be a single column that changes at a time.  Otherwise pd.from_dummies will raise an error.  A benefit of this approach is that it allows for the rows to not be sorted into the groups already, so changes in A do not all need to be consecutive.
Changes
If there are additional columns and you only want to look at the columns A, B and C, you can change the condition to
condition = pd.from_dummies(
    df[list("ABC")].ne(
        dict(A=1, B=10, C=100)
    )
).iloc[:, 0]

instead.  This select only the columns that you are interested in.
An error will be raised when using .ne(...) if the dictionary keys do not include all columns in the DataFrame (in this change, just columns A, B and C).

thank you for your answer. I have tried to implement this, however (my fault that I did not mention this), I have more than A, B and C columns in my dataframe. And those columns should not interfere with getting the different subgroups, but then I get an error in df_ne "Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 4: given 3"(for example if I have an extra column D in the dataframe). Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

I would compute the diff, then identify the values that are not null (i.e. changing), if there is more than 1 per row, this is the start of a new group (obtained with cumsum):
group = df.diff().ne(0).sum(axis=1).gt(1).cumsum()

for k, g in df.groupby(group):
    print(f'Group {k}:')
    print(g)

Output:
Group 1:
     A   B    C
0  0.5  10  100
1  1.0  10  100
2  1.5  10  100
3  2.0  10  100
4  2.5  10  100
Group 2:
     A   B    C
5  1.5   8  100
6  1.5   9  100
7  1.5  10  100
8  1.5  11  100
9  1.5  12  100
Group 3:
      A   B    C
10  1.5  10   60
11  1.5  10   80
12  1.5  10  100
13  1.5  10  120
14  1.5  10  140

Intermediates:
    A_diff  B_diff  C_diff  A_ne(0)  B_ne(0)  C_ne(0)  sum  gt(1)  cumsum
0      NaN     NaN     NaN     True     True     True    3   True       1
1      0.5     0.0     0.0     True    False    False    1  False       1
2      0.5     0.0     0.0     True    False    False    1  False       1
3      0.5     0.0     0.0     True    False    False    1  False       1
4      0.5     0.0     0.0     True    False    False    1  False       1
5     -1.0    -2.0     0.0     True     True    False    2   True       2
6      0.0     1.0     0.0    False     True    False    1  False       2
7      0.0     1.0     0.0    False     True    False    1  False       2
8      0.0     1.0     0.0    False     True    False    1  False       2
9      0.0     1.0     0.0    False     True    False    1  False       2
10     0.0    -2.0   -40.0    False     True     True    2   True       3
11     0.0     0.0    20.0    False    False     True    1  False       3
12     0.0     0.0    20.0    False    False     True    1  False       3
13     0.0     0.0    20.0    False    False     True    1  False       3
14     0.0     0.0    20.0    False    False     True    1  False       3


Only using some of the columns
If you have more columns and just want to use ['A', 'B', 'C'], simply select those:
df = pd.DataFrame({'i': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                   'A': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
                   'B': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                   'C': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140],
                   'D': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140], })

group = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].diff().ne(0).sum(axis=1).gt(1).cumsum()

for k, g in df.groupby(group):
    print(f'Group {k}:')
    print(g)

Output:
Group 1:
   i    A   B    C    D
0  1  0.5  10  100  100
1  2  1.0  10  100  100
2  3  1.5  10  100  100
3  4  2.0  10  100  100
4  5  2.5  10  100  100
Group 2:
    i    A   B    C    D
5   6  1.5   8  100  100
6   7  1.5   9  100  100
7   8  1.5  10  100  100
8   9  1.5  11  100  100
9  10  1.5  12  100  100
Group 3:
     i    A   B    C    D
10  11  1.5  10   60   60
11  12  1.5  10   80   80
12  13  1.5  10  100  100
13  14  1.5  10  120  120
14  15  1.5  10  140  140


Thank you. I have the same issue as the solution proposed by Rawson, as if I add more than three columns the method does not work. for example if df is df = pd.DataFrame({
'i': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
'A': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
'B': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
'C': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140],
'D': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140],
})  then I get 15 groups one for each row....

@robi_beginner if you just want to use A/B/C and ignore the other columns, just select them. See the example in my updated answer

Thanks. No the issue is the I want to use the other columns after the splitting, just they should not interfer while I create the sub dataframe

This might solve your problem:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
    'B': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    'C': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140]
})

variable_cols = [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique()) > 1]
subdfs = {}
for col in variable_cols:
    subdfs[col] = df.loc[df[col].diff().fillna(-1).ne(0)]

df_A = subdfs['A'].iloc[:5,:]
df_B = subdfs['B'].iloc[:5,:]
df_C = subdfs['C'].iloc[:5,:]


thanks. This works but it is a bit "manual": If I have a lot of columns, then I need to write a row for each columns to assig the sub dataframe...and this is not optimal
